# Отображение заголовка ComboBox при использовании списка из CheckBox?

Tags: wpf

Здравствуйте, господа.

Мне необходимо в заголовке ComboBox (текст отображаемый, когда список свернут и какой-то элемент в нем выбран) написать свой текст в зависимости от установленных галочек:
"Изнашивание", "Старение" или "Изнашивание + Старение".

```
<ComboBox Name="cb3"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,143,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456" Focusable="False">
  <CheckBox Content="Изнашивание"/>
  <CheckBox Content="Старение"/>
</ComboBox>
```

Подскажите, как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Ну, добавьте сверху прозрачный для мыши `TextBlock`, в него положите нужный текст через привязку + MultiValueConverter. А в чём проблема?

---

Без визуальных трюков не получится, т. к. вам хочется странного: комбобокс по гайдлайнам показывает выбранный item, а не то, что хочется левой пятке заказчика. Поэтому тупо рисуем нужный текст поверх.